# running into error 403 during terraform apply

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

Running terraform apply getting below error.

```
{"error":{"code":403,"message":"The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state absent","errors":[{"message":"The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state absent","domain":"global","reason":"accountDisabled","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}]}}: timestamp=2022-12-31T00:04:43.690-0500
```

For the project I added the billing account.

I am able to run gcloud commands from shell without any errors using the same service account.

```
terraform_gcp % gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=sakey.json
Activated service account credentials for: [gcp-terraform@saproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
terraform_gcp % gsutil ls
gs://mygcptfstatebucket/
terraform_gcp % gcloud compute instances list
Listed 0 items.
```

my main.tf is

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "4.47.0"
    }
  }
}


provider "google" {
  project = "my-gcp-project"
  region  = "us-east1"
  zone    = "us-east1-b"
}
```

Any insights into this error.

Comment: Never ever use service account key file. prefer this command line: `gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account=<service account email>`. Be sure to be (your user account) "service account token creator" on the service account (or the project) to impersonate it;

Answer (score 0):

Tried adding below block and its working seems issue with my configuration.

```tf
data "google_project" "project_name" {
    project_id = "projectid"
}
```

and referencing `project_id` in the resource block.